# Toast is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, android

I am self studying android projects and i am very new to android and java.
i cant figure out the error, please help,

```
Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

this gives me the error that i pasted below:
The method `makeText(Context, CharSequence, int)` in the type `Toast` is not applicable for the arguments `(new BleWrapperUiCallbacks.Null(){}, String, int)`

when i use "context" instead of "this", there is no error.
if i want to use "this" keyword means what should i do?
and what is the use of "this" keyword on `toast.maketext` function? thanking you.

Comment: where you want to show `Toast`?

Comment: Go to [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) and never ask this type of questions again..Plzzz

Comment: `activityname.this` insted `this` n try hope it works for u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want to use `this` as a pointer to an `Activity` in an anonymous inner class (e.g. `OnClickListener`), you have to use the `Activity` name before `this`: `MyActivity.this`, substitute with your Activity's name.

Answer (score 0):

this -

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to
>   the current object

You may use this only on object that are extending Context like Activity -

> Activity extends ContextThemeWrapper The method

`Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, CharSequence, int)`

in other case you should use context reference

Answer (score 0):

You could only use `this` keyword if you have this code in the context of the Activity class.
All gui in android have its context -> for example Activity, so to create object like toast you need to pass an `Context`.
If your method, in other class than Activity Subclass  is using `this`, pass a new parameter to your method -> `Context context`, and use it Like (in `Activity` class):
`MyClass.myFunction(YourActivity.this);`

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use this keyword, u can use like this,

```
Toast.makeText(Classname.this, msg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Where Classname is your android class name

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(youractivityname.this, "your message text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```